# Assigning Swift methods to variables

Tags: swift

Is there an way to make a method alias?

For example, I have a class which makes calculations for Circle: area, circumference, etc. In math area is written as "A", circumference as "C" and radius as "r", however for normal people and for code clarity it is obviously better to use full names for such calculations. Therefore I want class member "C" and class member "circumference" do essentially the same thing.

The obvious way is to assign method to a variable... But calling such method is unnecessary complicated. Here's the code:

```
class Circle: parentClass {
    let π = M_PI

    ...

    // here I try to "alias" a method
    let C = circumference

    func circumference() -> Double {
        return 2 * self.radius * π
    }
}
```

and now calling the method:

```
let instance = Circle()

// the line below actually calls instance.circumference
// but does not look clean enough to be useful
instance.C(instance)()
```

Is there more clever way to do this?

Comment: You could just forward the call, right? `func c() -> Double { return self.circumference() }`.

Comment: Yes, but I thought there is more elegant method than good old wrapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is more elegant; however, I do find it to be at least well-organized and ultimately a better API (using properties vs. methods):

```
struct Circle {
  let π = 3.14
  var radius: Double
  var circumference: Double { return self.π * diameter() }

  init(radius: Double) {
    self.radius = radius
  }

  func diameter() -> Double {
    return self.radius * 2
  }
}

extension Circle {
  var C: Double { return self.circumference }
}

let circle = Circle(radius: 60.0)
let circumference = circle.C

println("The circumference is: \(circumference)")
//=> The circumference is: 376.8
```

Comment: Thank you! Extensions is that bit of Swift knowledge I lacked to make things beautiful.